# Android Emulator Couchbase Replication Database not found error

Tags: android, docker, android-emulator, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

Facing an issue with the integration of couchbase sync-gateway with couchbase-server from an android emulator

**Environment Details**

1. Android Emulator running on Windows
2. Couchbase Lite installed on Windows
3. VirtualBox hosting couchbase server and sync-gateway Docker containers on Ubuntu

**Setup**

1. sync-gateway and couchbase-server able to communicate with each other as per the logs from the Docker container
2. Both Docker container are part of same network as mentioned in the documentation of Docker-hub couchbase
3. Port Forwarding enabled from the Windows to integrate with Virtual box and able to access 8091/4984/4985
4. Created a new database/bucket on couchbase-server : *rssfeeder*
5. Sync-gateway log confirms the server up and running with rssfeeder details

**Issue**
 1. Android Emulator starts the app having replication push/pull continues true
 2. Emulator initiate the remote connection and with IP address

```
http://10.0.2.2:4984/rssfeeder
```

Error log on console:

```
404 Not found
```

3. The database not able to access from the browser of host machine as well.

It would be really appreciated to get this going as I am working with couches/Docker/VM  first time

Comment: Have you tried accessing the Sync Gateway admin web server?  If you can't reach that from the host machine, it's an issue with Docker/Virtualbox config.

Comment: Yes you hit on the correct direction. When tried to reach the admin portal it is not as expected due to the Docker+Virtualbox and the host machine Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Double checking if you changed the default port that the Couchbase Sync Gateway listens to in your config file. 
If not, then note that the Sync Gateway listens on ports 4984(public) and 4985(admin). Your request says "4584".
Also, I would recommend making a http query directly using curl (or any http client) from your device to the sync gateway. If that works, you know your configuration is fine.

```
curl -X GET 'http://user:pass@localhost:4984/rssfeeder/_all_docs'
```

Comment: Yes the port is 4985 admin and 4984 public. I had created httpclient from plain Java as well as curl both are working fine. But emulator not able to resolve the connection with the sync-gateway Docker image on VM

Comment: If your ports are 4985/4984, then why does your original question indicate that the emulator uses the port "4584"  - "http://10.0.2.2:4584/rssfeeder" .